# Adicionar annotate com data no eixo x

Tags: ggplot2

Olá, estou tentando fazer um gráfico com os dados que pus nesse link em xlsx no google drive.

#https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RcZtpPRd5VsWQ_vc8KfFhcbtj9NcdwTL/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=110856289517796181233&rtpof=true&sd=true

#Minha dificuldade está em realizar uma anotação no gráfico, pois toda vez que tento dá erro. O script que fiz foi esse:

```
ggplot(pluviosidade1) +
 aes(x = datacerta, y = pluviosidade) +
  geom_line(aes(y = pluviosidade), color = "red", size = 1, group = 1) +
  geom_area(aes(y = pluviosidade), color = "red", fill = "red", 
            alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Freq*20), color = "blue", size = 1, group = 1) +
  geom_area(aes(y = Freq*20), color = "blue", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./20, name = "Acidentes Ofídicos")) + 
  labs(x = "Ano", 
       y = "Pluviosidade (mm)", title = "Pluviosidade e Acidentes Ofídicos")  +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 years",
               date_labels = "%Y") +
 theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", 
                                  hjust = 0.5))
```

#Até essa parte está tudo perfeito mas se eu adicionar isso ao código...

```
+ annotate(
    "text", label = "Spearman = 0,435   p-valor < 0,01", 
    x = "2019", y = 580, size = 3.0, colour = "black")
```

#Aparece o seguinte erro:

#Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Por favor, me ajudem. Além disso, gostaria de saber se vocês sabem fazer a área avermelhada ficar por cima da azulada, e não o contrário.

#Abraços

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro ponto: essa parte que vc diz que está "tudo perfeito", pelo menos para mim não rodou:

```
ggplot(pluviosidade1) +
  aes(x = datacerta, y = pluviosidade) +
  geom_line(aes(y = pluviosidade), color = "red", size = 1, group = 1) +
  geom_area(aes(y = pluviosidade), color = "red", fill = "red", 
            alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Freq*20), color = "blue", size = 1, group = 1) +
  geom_area(aes(y = Freq*20), color = "blue", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./20, name = "Acidentes Ofídicos")) + 
  labs(x = "Ano", 
       y = "Pluviosidade (mm)", title = "Pluviosidade e Acidentes Ofídicos")  +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 years",
               date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", 
                                  hjust = 0.5))
```

A mensagem:

> "Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only"

indica que é preciso transformar a variável para a classe "date"

Assim, a primeira providência foi alterar o trecho
`aes(x = datacerta, y = pluviosidade)`
para
`aes(x = as.Date(datacerta), y = pluviosidade)`

Esse, aliás, é o mesmo equívoco que impede a realização da função `annotate()`.

No parâmetro `x = "2019"` é preciso converter para data e colocar em um formato adequado: `x = as.Date("2019-01-01")`.

Sendo assim, o código ficaria:

```
ggplot(pluviosidade1) +
  aes(x = as.Date(datacerta), y = pluviosidade) +
  geom_line(aes(y = pluviosidade), color = "red", size = 1, group = 1) +
  geom_area(aes(y = pluviosidade), color = "red", fill = "red", 
            alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Freq*20), color = "blue", size = 1, group = 1) +
  geom_area(aes(y = Freq*20), color = "blue", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./20, name = "Acidentes Ofídicos")) + 
  labs(x = "Ano", 
       y = "Pluviosidade (mm)", title = "Pluviosidade e Acidentes Ofídicos")  +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 years",
               date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", 
                                  hjust = 0.5))+
  annotate("text", 
           label = "Spearman = 0,435   p-valor < 0,01", 
           x = as.Date("2019-01-01"), 
           y = 580, 
           size = 3.0, 
           colour = "black")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por fim, se sua inteção é colocar a cor vermelha adiante da azul, basta alterar a ordem no código.

```
ggplot(pluviosidade1) +
  aes(x = as.Date(datacerta), y = pluviosidade) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Freq*20), color = "blue", size = 1, group = 1) +
  geom_area(aes(y = Freq*20), color = "blue", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) +
  
  geom_line(aes(y = pluviosidade), color = "red", size = 1, group = 1) +
  geom_area(aes(y = pluviosidade), color = "red", fill = "red", 
            alpha = 0.6) +
  
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./20, name = "Acidentes Ofídicos")) + 
  labs(x = "Ano", 
       y = "Pluviosidade (mm)", title = "Pluviosidade e Acidentes Ofídicos")  +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 years", date_labels = "%Y")+
  
  annotate("text",
           label = "Spearman = 0,435   p-valor < 0,01", 
           x = as.Date("2019-01-01"), 
           y = 580, 
           size = 3.0, 
           colour = "black")+
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", 
                                  hjust = 0.5))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Caracas, vlw demais! Obrigado

Comment: @JorgeRocha Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.